# Visualforce :- I am facing some trouble while rendering page

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-id, visualforce-component

I have a page of my website..
In that page I have a registration forms and videos and some text...
When I register in registration page and then come back to this page already registered, then registration box disappears..
It looks I have left my rendered tags set to hide the reg form if they are logged in.

Code I am using for that --

```
<c:HomePageRightReglanding rendered="{!ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest')}" />
```

`HomePageRightReglanding` my component name where I have form to display ...

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you clarify what is the expected behaviour (what you want to happen) and what is the actual behaviour (what is happening).

Comment: @grigriforce I have updated my Question... !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you create ax extra custom boolean field on the User object like "Registered__c". By default it is "false" and after registration it is "true" (after log-off it is "false" again). And handle your component visibility based on that field:

```
public class YourClass{

    public User currentUser { get; set; }

    public YourClass(){
        currentUser = [ Select Registered__c From User Where Id = UserInfo.getUserId() ];
    }
}

<c:HomePageRightReglanding rendered="{!currentUser.Registered__c}" />
```

Or try to use `Userinfo.getSessionId()`. If the user is registered, he must get an Sesion-ID so `Userinfo.getSessionId() = true`